# Помощь с картинкой

Tags: изображения, php

Подскажите есть ли такие скрипты
У меня есть изображение мне на него нужно нанести текст, Допустим картинка называется "test.png", мне на него нужно нанести текст, допустим "Привет", подскажите как так сделать

Comment: Библиотека GD: [PHP GD Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.image.php)

Answer (score 2):

Для работы с изображениями в PHP используется библиотека GD:
http://www.php.net/manual/ru/ref.image.php - официальная документация
http://www.codenet.ru/webmast/php/gd/      - несколько уроков для начинающих